# Specifying ngram size and add one smoothing in indri

Tags: search-engine, information-retrieval

I am trying to use the indri search engine of the lemur project. I have the following questions:

1) How to do we specify an Ngram size for the Langauge model that indri builds during indexing.
2) How do we telll indri to use add one smoothing 
3) Can you use only the language model retrieval system of indri and NOT use its inference networks?

Thanks